# How to solve this compile error in iText (java)?

Tags: java, pdf, error-handling, itext, itext7

So, I'm currently working on a form filler code in iText, and for some reason, when I specify the right paths with file names for both source, and output, I'm getting the error shown below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.filters.DctDecodeFilter.<clinit>(DctDecodeFilter.java:60)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.filters.FilterHandlers.<clinit>(FilterHandlers.java:79)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.decodeBytes(PdfReader.java:444)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readStreamBytes(PdfReader.java:360)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readXrefStream(PdfReader.java:1127)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readXref(PdfReader.java:953)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:711)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.open(PdfDocument.java:1920)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:328)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:296)
    at itext.IText.main(IText.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 11 more
C:\Users\Bence\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.3\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Bence\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.3\executor-snippets\run.xml:94: Java returned: 1
```

Here's my code:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, java.io.IOException {
        String sourcePath = "E:\\NetBeansProjects\\iText\\sample.pdf";
        String filePath = "E:\\test.pdf";
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(sourcePath), new PdfWriter(filePath));
        PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true);
        Map<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.getFormFields();
        fields.get("name").setValue("Sample Sam");
        fields.get("birth").setValue("Los Angeles, 1998. 08. 05.");
        fields.get("mother").setValue("Maria Sam");
        fields.get("social").setValue("1554984");
        fields.get("address").setValue("Los Angeles, Nice Ave. 1.");
        // form.flattenFields();
        pdf.close();
        System.out.println("The PDF is done.");
    }
```

I know that there are topics with solutions, but none of them worked for me. I don't know if it's because of the older versions, or if there's something else, but I'd be glad if someone could help me out.

Comment: Have you slf4j in your class path?

Comment: Nope. Could you explain this one? I'm don't have much knowledge about slf4j.

Comment: [Slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) is simple-logging-facade-for-java. Itext depends on it being in the class path. For sensible logging you might also need a slf4j implementation like [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/).

Comment: And how can I put this slf4j into the class path?

Comment: Hm, how do you start your Java programs in general? Obviously in your attempt you already had the iText library in the class path, so just add it the same way.